# Search and convert a substring into a link. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have this string: "according to posts #4,#5 and #6 the word..."

I want to convert the "#4", "#5" and the "#6" to links, using the link_to helper (the numbers are ids of a Model)

How can I do this? Is this difficult? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good candidate for a helper method:

```
def link_ids(string)
  string.gsub(/#(\d+)/) do
    link_to "##{$1}", mymodel_path($1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"posts #4,#5 and #6".gsub(/(\#\d+)/) { |s| 
    link_to s, :controller => :word, :action => :show, :id => s[1,10].to_i
}
```